# String Var with int var

Tags: java

I want to have a string variable showing next to my int variable but it doesn't seem to work.

```
public class ThreeLittleNumbers {
    public static void main(String[] argts) {
        String as = "Number 1: ";
        String bs = "Number 2: ";
        String cs = "Number 3: ";
        int a = 1;
        int b = 3;
        int c = 5;
        String tot = "Total: ";
        System.out.println(as+a);
        System.out.println(bs+b);
        System.out.println(cs+c);
        System.out.println(tot);
        System.out.print(a+b+c);
    }
}
```

Comment: If the question is why is `a + b + c` on the next line, then that is because your have a `println` for `tot`. You need to `print(tot)` _then_ `println(a+b+c)`. Or, more simply, `println(tot + (a + b + c))`. Otherwise please clarify the question. P.S. consider using a `List`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, then this

```
System.out.println(tot);
System.out.print(a + b + c);
```

should be

```
System.out.print(tot);
System.out.println(a + b + c);
```

When I make the change above, I get output like you seem to be asking for -

```
Number 1: 1
Number 2: 3
Number 3: 5
Total: 9
```

Another option would be to use [`printf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) and something like

```
System.out.printf("%s %d%n", tot, a + b + c);
```

Comment: Or `println(tot + (a + b + c))`...